# Is there a way to re-enable "old-style" quit in Chrome?

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome, shortcut

I've just turned on my old Macbook for the first time in a couple years and found that now I have to hold command + Q in order to quit Chrome, whereas I used to be able to just tap it. I prefer the old way. Is there a way to re-enable that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a problem with Chrome, not MacOS. It's being done by the Chrome software. In the top menu, under Chrome, there's an option "Warn Before Quitting." Unchecking that turns the feature off.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using macOS since it was called System 6 and with one exception (that I found recently -- Google Chrome!) all you have to do to quit an App is **TAP** <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>. Including the latest macOS on several different Macs.

If you have to hold down that key combo there is either something wrong with your system (maybe even hardware) or there is something installed that could be configured to exhibit that behavior.

Start with logging in as another (new) user, then try a Safe Boot and see if it still behaves that way, and report back.

Comment: When I tap Command + Q, a system modal message flashes on the screen, telling me to hold it if I want to quit. Definitely not a hardware problem, at least. It doesn't *seem* like a third party behavior but I can't rule it out. I would screenshot it, but my mac is busy updating to Mojave right now. Maybe it'll be fixed afterwards and I won't have to.

Comment: Seconded -  Chrome does that; nothing else.

Comment: It was indeed a Chrome only thing. The solution is in the Chrome settings.